# Strange behavior with /bin/ca?

Tags: linux, bash

My version of bash:

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.04.

Reproduction:

```
env -i /bin/bash
/bin/ca?
```

I'm just now learning bash and I'm curious why the above snippet results in the following:

```
a@a:/$ /bin/ca?
cal: not a valid year /bin/cat
```

Afaik, this single ? is consumed as a wildcard, and is resolved to be /bin/cal. That much is clear, I guess.
Why in the world does this result in argv[1] becoming /bin/cat (I'm assuming)? What kind of magic is going on here?

EDIT:

```
strace /bin/ca?
```

Confirms that argv is modified:

```
execve("/bin/cal", ["/bin/cal", "/bin/cat"], 0x7ffed1f359b8 /* 54 vars */) = 0
```

Why is this so?

Comment: The google term is `globbing` (what does `echo /bin/ca?` say?)

Comment: perfect; thanks! i'd be perfectly fine with that as an answer for me to verify btw, much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately SO is for "fixing problems", not for teaching.